# How can i get entity object with contion JPA

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, stateless-session-bean

I have 2 Objects Site and Page.
A Site have many Pages. 
I get pages with fetch Lazy type.
With a particular reason i want to get pages of a site where the date of pages > val.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "site")
Public class Site {
String site_id;
Set<Page> pages;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Page> getPages() {
    return pages;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
Public class Page{
String page_id;
Site site;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    public Site getSite() {
    return site;
    }
}
```

Now in SiteDao i have the mothode to call a site and its pages

```
@Stateless
public class SiteDao {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "name")
private EntityManager em;

    public Site getSiteAndPages(String site_id) {        
    Query q = em.createQuery("select s From Site s where s.site_id = :site_id");
    q.setParameter("site_id", site_id);
    Site s = (Site) q.getSingleResult();
    s.getPages();        
    return s;
    }   
}
```

This turns well, but `s.getPages()` return all the pages and i want to get only some pages using where conditions.
I tried many options like:

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
            "select s, p From Site s"
            + " join s.pages p "
            + " where s.site_id = :site_id "
            + " and p.site = s"  
            + " and  p.lastupdate > :val"
            );
    q.setParameter("site_id", site_id); 
    q.setParameter("val", lastUpdate);
```

Im bloked after many searches, does any person have an idea about how can i fix this ?

B.R

Comment: So what happens? An Exception? Incorrect Results?

Comment: I doesn't work, it still always get all the pages when i call `s.getPages()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need some business methods, you can keep inside Site Class

There are two options
1. Add filter

```
getLatestPages(Date lastupdate)
{
  List pages_=  s.getPages();   
  List latestPages=new ArrayList();
  for(Page p: pages_)
  {
     if(p.getLastUpdatedate().after(lastupdate)) {
             latestPages.add(p);
     }
  }
  reutrn latestPages;
}
```

2.Use query

```
getLatestPages(EntityManager em, Date lastupdate)
{
 Query q = em.createQuery(
        "select p From Site s"
        + " join s.pages p "
        + " where s.site_id = :site_id "
        + " and p.site = s"  
        + " and  p.lastupdate > :val"
        );
      q.setParameter("site_id", this.site_id); 
      q.setParameter("val", lastUpdate);   
      return q.getResultList();  
}
```

Hope this work.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. Definitely it will works but the goal of my request is to improve memory performance and the `s.getPages` method cannot be a solution because it returns more than 500,000 pages. So i want to reduce this number by directly quering only some pages.

Comment: use 2nd option which returns as per your query

Comment: Thank you again, i tried the 2nd option but no result reterned by the query. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry, can not help more on this, You need to get familiar with JPA